# VisionOS - How to remove button background?

Tags: visionos

I'm trying to create a circular button in VisionOS, there is always a background oval that doesn't appear in the iOS version. I'm using SwiftUI and Xcode 15.2:

```
Button(action: {}) {
      Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill").resizable().frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)                                
}.background(Color.clear)
```

Changing the background has no effect, what I want is just the circle, but the button keeps adding an oval background that I don't want. How can I get rid of that background? Example of the undesired button is below:

[image]

PS: there seems to be the same problem with Navigation Links, the undesired background seems to be set there too. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Solved by adding .buttonStyle(.plain) to the button.